# run f# code on server even when f# is not installed there

Tags: f#

is it possible to run f# code on server if it's not installed there (shared server)? I mean maybe I can upload and reference all the necessary assemblies? [f# download place](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18706) contains zip for "other cli implementations" - maybe someone had simillar issues?

**Edit** More context: actually I'm using c# to compile and run f# program. So I call

```cs
using (CodeDomProvider provider = new Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider())
{
  cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, new string[] { data.Program });
}
```

Now on my machine everything is fine. I have included FSharp.Core.dll (version 4) as well as FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom (version 2). Everything is copied locally. On server I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider.CreateCompiler()
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateCompilerHelper()
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)...
```

**Edit2:**
So actually I wanted to *compile* f# code on a server with no f# installed. Here is what I had to do:

```
1. put FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll (version 2 as there is now newer now) and FSharp.Core.dll version 2 in bin directory.
2. create new directory in bin directory and put there this:
-FSharp.Compiler.dll (version 4)
-FSharp.Core (.dll, .xml, .sigdata, .optdata) (version 4)
-Fsc.exe - f# compiler
3. From code set process' FSHARP_BIN environment variable to point to above directory:
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FSHARP_BIN", Utils.RootFolder + @"bin\comilersstuff");
```

This way compilation is successful and if you'd want to run it, you'd had to put Fsharp.Core.dll (v. 4)  in the same directory as compiled F# program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

of course - just copy the FSharp-Dlls with your project or use the --standalone compiler option. Of course you will need the .net (4.0/3.5/2.0 depending of your F#-version) Framework on your server.

Easiest way to do the first: use the "Copy Local" settings for the References - the Dll will be put beside your .exe/.dll in the bin folder (or whereever you let your output go):
[image]

Comment: `FSharp.Core.dll` is redistributable, so you can just deploy it alongside your app, this is typically the easiest thing to do.  (You could also chain an installer to the installer of your app, see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee241127.aspx ).